# Array of movieclip classes

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have an array of movieclip classes

```
var array:Array = new Array(MovieClip1, MovieClip2, MovieClip3);
```

And then I'd like to create new instances of them. Something like:

```
var o:MovieClip = new array[0];
```

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: It works as is, check their class names in Symbol Properties menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MovieClip1, MovieClip2 are String then try,

```
var array:Array = new Array(MovieClip1, MovieClip2, MovieClip3);

var o:MovieClip = new ( getDefinitionByName(array[0]) as Class);
```

Comment: You're right , i was confused by OP's *"array of movieclip classes"*